# Accessing 32bit assembly array, memory addressing

Tags: assembly, x86

Hi I'm new to assembly currently coding in 32bit assembly and I'm trying to access an array I initialized.

This is the array

```
lookup: dd 0, 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish

```
add     bh, [lookup+al*4]
```

`al` is the index I want to add to `bh`

The code in c would be

```
b += a[i];
```

(`b` is `bh`, array is `lookup`, and `al` is `i`)

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: `al*4` isn't valid when specifying an address. Use `eax*4` instead (and make sure that the unused bits of `eax` are zeroed).

Comment: Thank you for your help! However now when I try to    mov     eax, al    I get an invalid number of opcode and operands error

Comment: Nevermind I'm stupid, al are the lower bits of eax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael [indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593145/accessing-32bit-assembly-array-memory-addressing/28599172#comment45492900_28593145) in the comments, you can't use `al` in an effective address. Instead, we'll zero-extend `al` into `eax`, and use it instead:

```
movzx   eax, al                   ; zero-extend 8-bit al into 32-bit eax
add     bh, [lookup + eax*4]
```